# jeditable vs editable in datatable - what's the difference

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable, jeditable

I am confused which plugin I should use with datatable jquery. My problem is I cannot find any answer that solve all my problems (I have suffered more than 4 hours now). Sorry if this problem has been already addressed countless times...

I have a table with >10000 rows from a mysql database, I wanna add a cell Inline editing on a specific column and so I found two existing methods.

1. http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html
2. http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit.html

My question is what are the differences ? Which one requires which js scripts as inputs (I got confused and added all of them at the end)...
I have the feeling that some are outdated and doesn't work anymore with the most recent versions. Or maybe I am mixing both of them, so nothing works at the end.

Jeditable (it doesn't work in my hand. when I click on any cell in the table, nothing happens)

```
$("#example.", oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable( 'php/editable_ajax.php', {
                    "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
                        var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                        oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
                    },
                    "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
                        return {
                            "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                            "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
                        };
                    },
                    "height": "14px"
                });
```

Editable (When I click, editing event works, but the value is not updated in the database, except if editable_ajax.php contains full mysql query, but then the page is not reloaded)

```
$('#example').dataTable().makeEditable({
                    sUpdateURL: "php/editable_ajax.php",
                    "aoColumns": [
                        null,
                        {
                            indicator: 'Saving CSS Grade...',
                            tooltip: 'Click to select CSS Grade',
                            loadtext: 'loading...',
                            type: 'select',
                            onblur: 'submit',
                            data: "{'':'Please select...', '1':'Yes','0':'No'}" 
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

PHP server side

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['value'].' (server updated)';
?>
```

One last question, is there one of them that handles more efficiently datatable with lots of row ? (it takes already 30 sec to load it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following prerequisite setup instructions tell me that you definitely need both jeditable and dataTables to make dataTables.editable work. [jquery-datatables-editable](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/HTMLSource)

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.DataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.jeditable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.DataTables.editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And by process of elimination, we can assume that you can jeditable is used solely with dataTables. Look at the [source of this example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html) and you can see only dataTables and jEditable have been used.

I'm not too sure about the differences, but I believe dataTables.editable provides an interface to some common functions between editable and dataTable (and jValidate) to make it easier to implement.

> This plugin integrates several plugins such as JQuery DataTables, JQuery Editable, JQuery Validation plugins and implement common data management functionalities.